# Is there a superclass implementing common operators?

Tags: matlab, oop, inheritance, overriding, data-class

I've recently wanted to create a simple data class for storing some physical quantity (temperatures) along with its known units. This class was supposed to have a `Data` property, containing an arbitrarily-sized `double` array, such that all common functions like `plus`, `minus`, `cat`, `reshape` etc. would simply use the value of `Data` and return a `double` array as a result (I don't even mind that the output isn't a new instance of the class).

However upon starting to implement this, it quickly became apparent that if I wanted to use such a class, I would have to implement tens of these [common functions/operators](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/implementing-operators-for-your-class.html#br02znk-6) just to get similar functionality to `double` - which is a lot of work for very little gain.

I figured that I might not be the first person to encounter this problem and so my question is: **Is there some existing class (e.g. *mixin*) we can inherit from, which defines the common functions/operators w.r.t. some default property?**

Alternatively, is there some class that implements a lot of these functions in its `classdef` so I could use it as a template? (Implementation convenience is a concern for me, so I'd prefer a template that is one large `classdef` instead of many separate files for each function.)

Comment: Why do you need the units, if you ignore them when doing arithmetic, and they disappear when applying any operation to the matrix? And if your arithmetic will ignore units anyway, why not just cast to double before applying those operations? Then all you need is a `double` method.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Originally I meant for internal unit conversions to happen when trying to perform computations on temperatures with different units, but the I realized that this is a total overkill for my needs. So the question (with all its peculiarities) is the result of me negotiating with myself about what I need for this task. Ideally, after arithmetics, I would get a new object of the class - but I realized that if wanted it to work this way - I'd likely have to implement all the methods (which defeats the purpose). I hope my reasoning is clear (even if somewhat flawed) :)

Comment: I don’t know if such a mixing exists or not, I think it would have limited utility. A template would make more sense, IMO. But if you have not found it, I won’t find it either. :) I have a class [here](https://github.com/DIPlib/diplib/tree/master/dipimage/%40dip_image) that overloads most of the common methods, only a few outside the classdef. Maybe you can use it as a start point: